# Is it possible to overload a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, specialization

I found that template method could be overloaded, can I do the same on template classes?  If 2 template classes match a template class instantiation, we can use the parameter type in the constructor to deduce which one to use.

```
template <typename T>
class A{
  A(T){}
};

template <typename T>
class A{
  A(T*){}
};

int main(){
  A<int*> a((int*)0);
  A<int> a((int*)0);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just so you know: the backtick syntax is for inline code. When you want to format blocks of code, indent each line by four spaces. http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/

Comment: template classes can be specialized (partially or completely)

Comment: @Jonathan Sterling, thanks for your hint. how can I indent a block code for 4 spaces? It seems tab on the whole block doesn't work. Is there any short cut to do this? Or I need to insert spaces line by line?

Comment: Tan: 4 spaces is not the point here. The point is that code snippet should look like code with some indentation at least. Use the '101' icon in the toolbar

Comment: Selecting lines of code and hitting ctrl-k (or the 101 button) is the best way to handle code listings.

Comment: What you want is not really overloading, because your two templates have the same kind of parameter (a type). Your requirement is closer to [pattern matching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching) in functional programming, where different implementations are selected based on the *value* of the parameter (not its *type*). Templates allow pattern matching through (partial) specialization.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. This is not allowed. Instead class template can be specialized (including partial specialization). This pretty much achieves the effect of overloading (which is only for functions)

Note that template parameters can not be deduced from constructor arguments.

```
template<class T> struct X{
   void f(){}
};

template<class T> struct X<T*>{
   void f(){}
};

int main(){
   X<int> x;
   x.f();          // calls X<T>::f

   X<int *> xs;
   xs.f();         // calls X<T*>::f
}
```